# Suggest an Alternative for glTranslate() load on CPU

Tags: opengl

I have been working on a project of OpenGL. Here I just display a boat moving along with some option's for view change.. Its a 2D program. The thing is I have used many glTranslate functions for moving the boat in the code. It works properly in Windows(DEV-CPP) but when executed in **Fedora it has a very very very slow movement for boat**. When checked for the CPU LOAD it was huge. So any thing which i can try to move the boat faster?

Please help :)

Comment: you would be surprised how many glTranslates any 3d app has... anyways.. you can manually move the points since it is a 2d app.. keep incrementing-decrementing them and call redisplay.. make sure u use double buffer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely that you don't have hardware acceleration in your Fedora version. Check that you've got the proprietary drivers from nvidia (or whoever manufacturs your video card) installed.

Also, do other OpenGL programs run fast?

Comment: Yes the other OpenGl functions do run. Like there is this rotation of Cube it does rotate fast.. In this code i have too many glTranslate functions used. so i guess the memory utilization is also too much..
I didnt understand the second part of your suggestion. What exactly you want me to do? I have an Intel G card

Comment: I started checking other program with glTranslate ... it is slow.. . which means linux hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the fact that Intel has a horrible Linux driver.

When you say you have too many glTranslate's, how many is too many?  Thousands per frame?  If you have a lot of translate calls called back to back, you can always add them up by hand and then call glTranslate once with the sum.  I'd be suspicious if that's what's slowing your machine down.

Comment: There's no reason to call `glTranslate` more than once per object per frame.  Ideally you avoid the call altogether (and pass your own transform matrices) as it is deprecated in 3.x contexts.

Comment: it cant happen.. its in for loop and also many other things come for the trouble.. anyways thankx for your reply. :)